# Oracle sql insert data in columns separately

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to insert data in table's columns separately so that the columns wouldn't affect each other. So far I've got to this:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_TABLE
(
 SERVER_NETWORK_NAME VARCHAR(15),
 SERVER_STORAGE_TB NUMBER,
 SERVER_LAUNCH_DATE DATE,
 MANIFACTURER VARCHAR2(5),
 THREADS NUMBER,
 CPU_LOAD NUMBER,
 QUERY_DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE (SERVER_NETWORK_NAME)  
     SELECT 'First network' from dual
     union all select 'Second network' from dual
     union all select 'Third network' from dual;

INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE (SERVER_STORAGE_TB)  
     SELECT 7 from dual
     union all select 14 from dual
     union all select 30 from dual;
```

The problem is that when I execute the second `INSERT` command it starts inserting at 4th row instead of 1st. How do I work on columns separately?

P.s. I can't insert data in all columns at once since these columns should have different row count.

Comment: I'm not sure how your real data looks like, but I usually have ID column and I replace the second `insert` with `update` statement

Comment: Since this is a school assignment, the data is only imaginary. This table stores some predefined data to be later randomly selected and stored in other tables.

Comment: If you insert data into table, you can not insert same row for other column, for that u can use update

Comment: `INSERT` is for _creating_ new rows while `UPDATE` is for _modifying_ rows which already exist.  I suspect you want to use `UPDATE` in your second set of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:
I keep inserting data the way I did before and when randomly selecting values from a column, I simply add a check if the value isn't null.

The random select code looks like this:

```
SELECT SERVER_STORAGE_TB FROM
(SELECT SERVER_STORAGE_TB FROM DATA_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1 AND SERVER_STORAGE_TB IS NOT NULL
```